# remove or hide horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have css file which declares loading icon like

```
#loading {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('loading.gif');
    background-position: center;
}
```

And it works perfectly loading icon appears until page loads but while loading icon is displayed I see horizontal scroll bar, which disappears after page loads. Can I hide or remove horizontal scroll bar when loading icon is displayed?

Comment: Without code I can't say much, but still add `left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0` and remove width and height

Answer (score 1):

Try using `overflow-x: hidden`. It would hide the horizontal scrollbar. Using `overflow: hidden` would hide both the vertical and horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: using `overflow:hidden` would hide both the vertical and horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #loading {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background-image: url('loading.gif');
   background-position: center;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS property `overflow: hidden;` hides all scrolls and disables any scrolling as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following CSS to your page:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope I helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x:hidden;`to hide horizontal scrollbar.

```
#loading {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background-image: url('loading.gif');
   background-position: center;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```